Wildfly 34.0.1 deployment error: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.PostgresDS"]
I am trying to deploy my web application via wildfly maven plugin and get the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:5.0.1.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project workerService: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.PostgresDS"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["service jboss.persistenceunit.\"workerService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#default\"._FIRST_PHASE_ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.PostgresDS]","service jboss.persistenceunit.\"workerService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#default\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.PostgresDS]"]}}} -> [Help 1]

my persistence.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             version="2.2">

    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <jta-data-source>java:/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.spo.workerService.entity.Person</class>
        <class>com.spo.workerService.entity.Coordinates</class>
        <class>com.spo.workerService.entity.Location</class>
        <class>com.spo.workerService.entity.Worker</class>
        <properties>
             <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5436"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="poouo"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="update"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

PostgreSQL JDBC driver dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.7.4</version>
</dependency>

I am using java 23.0.1, wildfly 34.0.1 and latest jakarta dependencies.

Is your datasource properly defined in wildfly configuration?

Are you deploying the Postgres driver to WildFly? Did you install it as a module?
